# html2pdf autocompletar campos

Tags: php, html

Con html2pdf quiero que se llene automáticamente algunos campos del documento pero haciendo pruebas no me detecta las variables,
este es el código que muestra los datos en el pdf

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

 <?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
    }


require_once ("config/db.php");
require_once ("config/conexion.php");

$active_prestamos="active"; 
$title="Prestamos   | Simple Stock";
?>
<HTML lang="es">
<HEAD>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Generar PDFs con PHP</title>
<style type="text/css">

    h2{
        color:darkslateblue;
    }


   </style>
 </HEAD>
<body>

 <h2>   hola</h2>
    <?php     
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    echo  $orden=$row['orden'];?>
    </body>
       </HTML>
```

y este es el que lo llama

```
            <?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

 use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;


 ob_start();
 require_once 'pdf2.php';
 $html = ob_get_clean();

$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('p','A4','es','true','UTF-8');
$html2pdf-> writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->output('pdf_generated.pdf');

?>
```

y el error

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: orden in C:\wamp64\www\inventario\pdf2.php on line 54
>   Call Stack
>
> ## Time Memory Function Location

1 0.0010 240048 {main}( ) ...\pdf.php:0
2 0.0040 378992 require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\inventario\pdf2.php' ) ...\pdf.php:8

Comment: El te esta diciendo que el índice order que llamas en $row['orden'] no existe, donde estas declarando el array $row ?

Comment: si lo intente declarar pero igual no ya edito la pregunta

Comment: $row['orden']  no puede existir simplemente porque estás asignando el resultado de una consulta SQL que es un `COUNT`... ¿Ves el problema ahora?

Comment: ps si pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes explorar también el uso de la utilidad wkhtmltopdf publicada por https://wkhtmltopdf.org/  y que puedes integrar a tu script mediante la función exec. Ej:

```
   exec ("<WkhtmltopdfPATH>/wkhtmltopdf.exe  $PathArchivoHTML $PathArchivoPDFGenerado ");
```